# How to initialize a flow in viewmodel with a suspend function as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am working with room database and datastore .
Here is my code

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class SubscriptionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userDataStore: UserDataStore,
    private val walletDao: WalletDao
) : ViewModel() {

val flow: Flow<List<Transaction>> = walletDao.getAllTransactions(userDataStore.getId()) 
 // This shows an error as userDataStore.getId() is a suspend function in DataStore


 init {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            getWalletAmount()
        }
    }
}
```

DataStore

```
 suspend fun getId(): String {
        val preferences = dataStore.data.first()
        return preferences[USER_ID] ?: ""
    }
```

WalletDao

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM recent_transactions where user_id=:user_id")
    fun getAllTransactions(user_id: String): Flow<List<Transaction>>
```

The problem is I am unable to initialise the flow. I tried initialising it in the init{ } block using lateinit , but while accessing in the fragment it crashes saying flow has not been initialised.

Any solution would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap it in a flow builder.

```
val flow: Flow<List<Transaction>> = flow {
    val source = walletDao.getAllTransactions(userDataStore.getId())
    emitAll(source)
}
```

If you want it to pre-load (start getting the first value even before anything collects the flow), then you should turn it into a SharedFlow by tacking this on:

```
.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, replay = 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

as I know you can call suspend fun in variable it must in init or in function
There is another solution

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class SubscriptionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userDataStore: UserDataStore,
    private val walletDao: WalletDao
) : ViewModel() {
        
    val flow= MutableStateFlow<List<Transcation>>(listOf())
       
    // then add value in init or anywhere 
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            flow.emit() // add value here
        }
    }
}
```